# Bootstrap Resampling vs Repeated K-Fold Cross-Validation for Confidence Intervals

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, predictive-models, resampling

Why is bootstrap resampling with replacement used to construct confidence intervals over repeated K-fold cross-validation? Isn't it valid to use 10-fold CV repeated 10 times, where we garner 100 data points from which we can construct a 95% confidence interval for a mean metric? Can someone explain how bootstrap resampling and CV differ and why the former allows for the construction of CIs?